# grand total in ORACLE SQL query?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

which query script to sum up total each row for each customer?

here are example below;

| customer | car | truck | 4WD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albert | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Joe | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Catherine | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Mark | 3 | 0 | 1 |

output like this to sum up total;

| customer | has_item |
| --- | --- |
| Albert | 2 |
| Joe | 1 |
| Catherine | 1 |
| Mark | 4 |

Many thanks

I tried

SUM(CASE when xx then x else x end) statement = which output wrong sum total

also sum(rownum) = didn't work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just

```
select customer,
       car + truck + "4WD" as has_item
from your_table
```